# How to properly implement observable list to populate a combobox

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, observablelist

I'm currently making a project that will act as a calendar. Currently i'm trying to implement a combobox that will allow the user to choose which month they want to skip to. Im having trouble implementing the observable list. I have look at other tutorials but it seems as though I'm still having problems actually getting the combobox to pick up what is in the list. Are my parameters for the observableArrayList function incorrect?
https://github.com/zhadjah9559/Side_Proj_Calendar.git

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {


@FXML
private Pane top, bottom, leftPane;

@FXML
private GridPane CalendarPane;

@FXML
private Label monthTitle, eventsListLabel, createEventsLabel, createdEventsLabels;

@FXML 
private TextArea bottomTextArea;

@FXML
private DatePicker datePicker;



//Creating an observable list to populate comboBox
private ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("month"); //only testing

public ObservableList<String> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(ObservableList<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

//populating the comboBox
@FXML
private ComboBox chooseMonth;




// individual dates or days (monday - sunday)
@FXML
private Label Label00, Label02, Label03, Label04,Label05,Label10,
        Label11, Label12, Label13, Label14, Label15, Label20, Label21,
        Label22, Label23, Label24, Label25, Label30, Label31, Label32,
        Label33, Label34, Label35, Label40, Label41, Label42, Label43,
        Label44, Label45, Label50, Label51, Label52, Label53, Label54,
        Label55, Label60, Label61, Label62, Label63, Label64, Label65;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    chooseMonth.setItems(list);
}    

@FXML
private void loadFebruary(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {   
    Parent registerPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("February.fxml"));
    Scene ViewScene = new Scene(registerPane);

    Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    window.setScene(ViewScene);
    window.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not even compile as written. You are trying to pass a `String` to your `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` method. That method does not accept a `String` argument.

To create a proper `ObservableList`, you need to pass an actual `List` to the method. Here is one such example, using `Arrays.asList()` to generate the `List` on-the-fly:

```
ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableList(Arrays.asList("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"));
```

From there, you can just set the `ComboBox` items:

```
comboBox.setItems(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is similar to what Zephyr suggested, but it is slightly different.  The primary difference is at the end, allowing a default value to be set in the combo box.

In my project, a table view is being populated with information based on what value is currently selected in the combo box. And maybe this is a user error thing, but by default, my combo box was blank when starting up, so the program was reading an error and was unable to run properly. So adding a default value in the combo box fixed my problem.

Place this code after your FXML items like buttons, textfields, etc. to create the list:

```
private final ObservableList<String> allMonths = FXCollections.observableArrayList("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
```

and under your initialize method, populate that list with this:

```
monthComboBox.setItems(allMonths);
```

You could also take it a step further by setting one of the items in the list (i.e. January) as the default choice by placing this after populating the list:

```
monthComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

All in all, the FXMLController would look like this, assuming proper imports above (because I don't remember all of them off the top of my head):

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private ComboBox<String> monthComboBox;

    private final ObservableList<String> allMonths = FXCollections.observableArrayList("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    monthComboBox.setItems(allMonths);
    monthComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }
}
```